# LP locker for Solana

Tags: spl-token, sol

Does anyone offer a process for locking liquidity in Solana projects? I can’t find anyone like pinksale for solana

Answer (score 2):

Streamflow is a solana protocol that provides token payment streams, vesting, and lockups. Your scenario would be solved by using a token lockup for a set time period, i.e. 1 year or 3 years or 99 years depending on your needs.

Their documentation on this feature:
https://docs.streamflow.finance/official-streamflow-docs/basics/token-lock